# Return only single column from Laravel hasOne relation

Tags: laravel

I'm creating custom form fields and in one table I save the field types, ex:

```
CustomFieldTypes
-------------------------------
id |    type     | common_name
-------------------------------
1  | v-text-area | TextArea
-------------------------------
```

Then in another table I save the details of the created custom field, ex:

```
PageCustomFields
----------------------------------------------------------
id | page_id | custom_field_type_id | label | is_required
----------------------------------------------------------
2  |    2    |          1           | Name  | false
----------------------------------------------------------
```

When I retrieve the PageCustomFields model I want to include ONLY the CustomFieldType's "type" field, I don't need the other field. How can I accomplish this? I've tried something like this in the PageCustomFields model but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public function customFieldType(){
   return $this->hasOne(CustomFieldType::class, "id", "custom_field_type_id")->select('type');
}
```

Any advise?
Thanks!

EDIT:
To clarify, I'd like the final PageCustomFields model attributes to look something like this after retrieving the CustomFieldTypes's type field:

```
PageCustomFields
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | page_id | custom_field_type | custom_field_type_id | label | is_required
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  |    2    |    v-text-area    |          1           | Name  | false
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you relation should be:

```
public function customFieldType(){
   return $this->belongsTo(CustomFieldType::class, "custom_field_type_id");
}
```

I prefer to define relationships without constraints, then apply needed constraints in controllers' code:

```
$value=PageCustomField::with('customFieldType:id,type')->get();
```

note this will select only `id`(needed for loading) and `type`.

anyway , if you want it that way you can use addSelect:

```
 public function customFieldType(){
       return $this->belongsTo(CustomFieldType::class, "custom_field_type_id")->addSelect(['CustomFieldTypes.id','CustomFieldTypes.type']);
    }
```

and if yow want it as normal select without nesting you can join the tables:

```
$values=PageCustomField::join('CustomFieldTypes','PageCustomFields.custom_field_type_id','=','CustomFieldTypes.id')->select('CustomFieldTypes.*')
->addSelect(['type']);
```

Comment: Doing it via controllers is fine, but I'd prefer not to have to do it every time I retrieve the PageCustomField model. So I'd like the type to always be included in the PageCustomField model no matter where it is accessed, hence me trying to access the custom field type directly in the model

Comment: ok, you can try addSelect, like the updated answer

Comment: That seems to work fine thank you but out of curiosity, would it be possible to simply pluck the "type" value and set that as the "customFieldType" field in the PageCustomField model without it being nested? I.e. Instead of it being `customFieldType = [ 'id' => 1, 'type' => 'v-textarea' ]` is it possible to simply set `customFieldType = 'v-textarea'` in the PageCustomField model? Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: I've edited my question to be a bit more clear on how I want the data to show

Comment: ok, you can try joining tables, like the updated answer

Comment: ->addSelect(['type as label']) if you want it with label head

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to do this join from within the model itself?

Comment: yes, you can do it inside the model

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head; does this work?

```html
public function customFieldType(){
   return $this->hasOne(CustomFieldType::class, "id", "custom_field_type_id")->type;
}
```

If not, assuming you're using Vue as a front end, perhaps you could use Laravel Resources to filter out only the information you want.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, it returns an "Undefined property" error